# Near initialization error in objective c

Tags: objective-c, macos

Why am I getting:

> this error control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
const int MAX = 4;

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
   char names[] = {
                   "Zara Ali",
                   "Hina Ali",
                   "Nuha Ali",
                   "Sara Ali",};
    char *pointer[MAX];
    for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    {
        pointer[i] = &names[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
       NSLog(@"Value of var[%d] = %s\n", i, *pointer[i] );
    }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Minor standardization of English.

Answer (score 0):

A vector of chars is not the same as a vector of strings. A `char` has space for just one character. `char[]` is a vector of characters, not a vector of strings. If you initialise it like this:

```
char names[] = {
    "Zara Ali",
    "Hina Ali",
    "Nuha Ali",
    "Sara Ali",};
```

The names variable will keep the pointer just to the first string, it will be initialised just with the first string. All the next strings will be ignored.

I think you are trying to do something like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
const int MAX = 4;

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSString *names[] = {
        @"Zara Ali",
        @"Hina Ali",
        @"Nuha Ali",
        @"Sara Ali",};
    NSString *pointer[MAX];
    for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    {
        pointer[i] = names[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"Value of var[%d] = %@\n", i, pointer[i] );
    }
    return 0;
}
```